# Trying to implement Priority Round Robin in xv6 but running into booting error

Tags: c, scheduler, riscv, xv6

I'm trying to implement the priority round robin scheduling system in xv6 after fixing some lock errors which were causing a panic error but now I keep running into a booting error and my kernel gets stuck before booting up completely.

```
xv6 kernel is booting

hart 2 starting
hart 1 starting
```

After this my kernel stops booting and gets stuck.

Sometimes the hart starting order changes from 1 then 2 and sometimes 2 then 1 starts.

My scheduler is defined in proc.c as follows:-

```
scheduler(void)
{
  struct proc *p;
  struct cpu *c = mycpu();
  struct proc *highp = 0;
  
  c->proc = 0;
  for(;;){
    // Avoid deadlock by ensuring that devices can interrupt.
    intr_on();

    for(p = proc; p < &proc[NPROC]; p++) {
      if (p->state != RUNNABLE)
      continue;
      if (highp == 0 || p->priority > highp->priority)
      highp = p;
      if (highp != 0) {
        continue;
      }
      }

      if (ticks-lastagingtime > 100) {
        struct proc *p;
        for (p = proc ; p < &proc[NPROC]; p++) {
          if (p->state == SLEEPING || p->state == RUNNABLE)
          p->priority++;
        }
        lastagingtime = ticks;

      }
     
    }
  }
```

My setpriority  is defined in proc.c as follows:-

```
setpriority(int pid, int priority)
{
  struct  proc *p;
  for (p = proc; p < &proc[NPROC]; p++) {
    if (p->pid == pid) {
       p->priority = priority;
    }
  }
    return pid;
}
```

I acquired a spinlock for looping over process table and then released it in the end then returned the pid value.

Now I keep running into this booting error and my kernel gets stuck.

Any idea how to solve this error or what necessary changes I should make?

I'm a beginner and any inputs would be extremely helpful !

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You still (because I remember the first question version) have issue in for loops:

- You do not lock spinlock before modifying `proc` (`acquire` / `release` functions)
- You do not switch to process to run it (`swtch` function)

I think (I didn't test it, I didn't have installed the needed qemu) that a corrected code should looks like:

```c
scheduler(void)
{
    struct proc *p;
    struct cpu *c = mycpu();
    struct proc *highp = 0;
 
    c->proc = 0;
    for(;;){
        // Avoid deadlock by ensuring that devices can interrupt.
        intr_on();
        
        // try to find the highest priority process and put in in highp
        for(p = proc; p < &proc[NPROC]; p++) {
            acquire(&p->lock);
            if (p->state == RUNNABLE && (highp == 0 || (p->priority > highp->priority))) {
                highp = p;
            }
            release(&p->lock);
        }
        
        // at this point highp is the highest priority process to run
        acquire(&highp->lock);
        highp->state = RUNNING;
        c->proc = highp;
        swtch(&c->context, &highp->context);
        release(&highp->lock);
        
        
        if (ticks-lastagingtime > 100) {
            struct proc *p;
            for (p = proc ; p < &proc[NPROC]; p++) {
                acquire(&p->lock);
                if (p->state == SLEEPING || p->state == RUNNABLE)
                    p->priority++;
                release(&p->lock);
            }
            lastagingtime = ticks;
        }     
    }
}
```

```c
setpriority(int pid, int priority)
{
    struct  proc *p;
    for (p = proc; p < &proc[NPROC]; p++) {
        acquire(&p->lock);
        if (p->pid == pid) {
            p->priority = priority;
        }
        release(&p->lock);
    }
    return pid;
}
```

**But** I don't think that you `priority` field is used well.

You should have two members:

- `base_priority` (set by `setpriority` syscall)
- `dynamic_priority` increased by the second `for` loop in `scheduler()`)

and the `dynamic_priority` should be used to determine which process is to be runned (first `for` loop) and reset to `base_priority` after the process is runned (after `swtch` call)

---

This part of answer was bound to the first question version: acquire/release was placed quite randomly into `for` loops.

Your problem is in the `for` loops.

In `scheduler` and `setpriority` functions, the pattern is

```c
for (p = proc...) {
    acquire(&p->lock);
    
    // some processing
    
    release(&p->lock);
}
```

If during *some processing* you call `continue` or `break`, the spinlock (`p->lock`) acquired won't be released.

Yet calling `acquire` on a already acquired spinlock leads to a kernel panic (see `acquire` definition in `kernel/spinlock.c` file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification I removed the locks and the panic error stopped occurring. But when I'm trying to reboot xv6, it's showing a new problem as follows:-

`xv6 kernel is booting

hart 1 starting
hart 2 starting`

After this the kernel stops booting. I'm really confused about what to do.

Comment: @AyxuxPlease edit your question to post the code that is actually running, please to not post image, and use formatting options, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code